# Can Cron Jobs Use Gnome-Open?

Tags: bash, cron, dbus

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 (Unity interface) and I created a Bash script that uses 'gnome-open' to open a series of web pages I use every morning. When I manually execute the script in the Terminal, the bash script works just fine. Here's a sample of the script (it's all the same so I've shortened it):

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-open 'https://docs.google.com';
gnome-open 'https://mail.google.com';
```

Since it seemed to be working well, I added a job to my crontab (mine, not root's) to execute every weekday at a specific time.

Here's the crontab entry:

```
30 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5 ~/bin/webcheck.sh
```

The problem is this error gets returned for every single 'gnome-open' command in the bash script:

> GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
>   Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
>   GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running
>   Error: no display specified

I did some searching to try and figure this out. The first thing I tried was relaunching the daemon using SIGHUP:

```
killall -s SIGHUP gconfd-2
```

That didn't work so I tried launching the dbus-daemon using this code from the manpage for dbus-launch:

```
## test for an existing bus daemon, just to be safe
         if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ; then
## if not found, launch a new one
         eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
         echo "D-Bus per-session daemon address is: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"
         fi
```

But that didn't do anything.

I tried adding simply 'dbus-launch' at the top of my bash script and that didn't work either.

I also tried editing the crontab to include the path to Bash, because I saw that suggestion on another thread but that didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can get this up and running?

Comment: For the record: use a browser with saved sessions (Chrome, Opera, Firefox all support it!), preferrably `pinned` tabs to (Chrome and Firefox; Opera has _stacked tabs_ too. Win!). That way, you won't have to play hacks like these to open a browser tab :)

Comment: Personally, I hate pinned tabs. But thanks for your answer below sehe, I'll play around and see if I can incorporate it into my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the problem was solved. It turns out the issue was primarily caused by Bash not having access to an X window session (or at least that's how I understood it). So my problem was solved by editing my crontab like so:

```
30 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5 export DISPLAY=:0 && ~/bin/webcheck.sh
```

The "export DISPLAY=:0" statement told cron which display to use. I found the answer on this archived Ubuntu forum after searching for "no display specified" or something like that:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-105250.html

So  now, whenever I'm logged in, exactly at 10:30 my system will automatically launch a series of webpages that I need to look at every day. Saves me having to go through the arduous process of typing in my three-letter alias every time :)

Answer (score 2):

Glad you asked!

It depends on when it is run.

If the Gnome GDM Greeter is live, you can use the DBUS session from the logon dialog, if you will. You can, e.g., use this to send notifications to the logon screen, if no-one is logged in:

```
function do_notification
{
    for pid in $(pgrep gnome-session); do
        unset COOKIE
        COOKIE="$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ|cut -d= -f2-)"
        GNUSER="$(ps --no-heading -o uname $pid)"

        echo "Notifying user $GNUSER (gnome-session $pid) with '$@'"
        sudo -u "$GNUSER" DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$COOKIE" /usr/bin/notify-send -c "From CRON:" "$@"
    done

    unset COOKIE
}
```

As you can see the above code simply runs the same command (`notify-send`) on all available gnome-sessions, when called like:

```
do_notification "I wanted to let you guys know"
```

You can probably pick this apart and put it to use for your own purposes.

Comment: You can usually rely on `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0` for the first session.

Comment: @ephemient: Nice. But _which_ home would you use if no vty are logged on to?

Comment: Thanks again sehe for your help. So I did some research to understand what your script was doing on a line-by-line basis. And I think I've got it.

So to get this to work for my purposes, I basically need to use the 'pgrep' method to determine the gnome-session PID, and then grab the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS from the gnome-session and set that in gnome-open. I assume I'd also have to use the COOKIE variable to unset the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in gnome-open to clean things up tidily?

Comment: @metaflops Well, the DBUS_* variable lives inside the super-user shell only as written. The COOKIE, GNUSER loop vars are just locals to make things... less illegible. I could (should) have made COOKIE/GNUSER a local declarations in my function. I guess I didn't know about that when I wrote this, and I wanted to prevent 'leaking' the last used DBUS* information by unsetting the COOKIE (which isn't actually as safe as a _local_ since it may have potentially overwritten a global shell variable by the same name).

Comment: Okay, so you would write "local" in front of the variable declarations, and forget about the "unset" business since the variables are being contained within the function?

Comment: OMG! I got it to work by simply editing my crontab to `30 10 * * 1,2,3,4,5 export DISPLAY=:0 && ~/bin/webcheck.sh` Well, sehe thanks for your help. I may not have used your code to solve my problem, but I sure learned a lot by breaking it down :)

Comment: @metaflops: haha. You had me on the wrong foot by mentioning DBUS :) Still, any application that requires DBUS and an exiting gnome session, still will have to include this hack.

Comment: Yeah, I was caught up on the whole DBUS thing, I ignored the Display issue or at least put it on the backburner over the DBUS thing. Anyway, thanks again.